# Работа приложения до указанной даты

Tags: android, время

Требуется, чтобы в заранее установленное время приложение переставало работать и отправляло в гугл плей для обновления (например, включалась только активность с отправкой в ГП). Это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Прекрасный способ лишиться потребителей.

Comment: сценарии могут быть разными. вопрос не в эффекте, а в технической реализации

Comment: Непонятно в чем суть проблемы? Время узнать и сравнить? UI блокировать?

Comment: А техническая реализация тривиальна - получаем текущую дату (системную либо внешнюю), сравниваем с захардкоденной, и в зависимости от результата делаем или не делаем то или иное...

Comment: проверяйте при запуске версию приложения в ГП и локальную, если в ГП есть новая версия - просите пользователя обновить приложение.